# Possible coolant leak?

Tags: motorcycle, coolant, coolant-leak

Over the course of the last 6000km on my FZ8 motorcycle I have noticed a small coolant level drop. I estimated the volume has dropped about 100cc. 
My motorcycle engine has reached 18.000km approximately. 
(From an almost MAX level on my overflow reservoir I needed to add about 100cc to reach it again so now I can be more specific next time I check it.) 
Also there are no coolant leaks visible on tubes, around the engine surfaces into the oil discoloring it or any drips on the motorcycle parking spot

I have also checked this [How does the coolant disappear?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/21403/how-does-the-coolant-disappear)

So if I was not mistaken and the motorcycle actually consumed 100cc of coolant over the course of these 6000km, would this be normal, tolerable or should I be alarmed?

Is there a way to check for coolant leaks through the combustion chamber in such small amounts?

Is this kind of "consumption" accepted for sports motorcycles in general?

Thank you

Comment: So, if you read the answer to the question you linked to, what else do you think is happening in your case?

Comment: Also, what period of time are we talking? Not just mileage but time in months or years. To me, 100ml would seem like more than general evaporation if we're talking talking about a couple months, but even that is variable. If it's over a span of a year or more, then that wouldn't seem like much.